# How can I get tab bar and bottom bar info from a .js file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a top bar and bottom bar in my Home Screen. What I want to do is I have an object, call it routeNames.js . I want the room names as my top bar navigator, and room items(laptop, tv etc) as bottom bar navigator.

I just did it without using routeNames.js data,  but i want to do it by using the data, and create my navigators.
Other question is how can I have bigger icon in bottom navigator? Now it seems so small

Here is how my project looks now:[image]

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View  } from "react-native";
import roomsList from "../routeNames";

import LivingRoom from "../rooms/LivingRoom";
import Kitchen from "../rooms/Kitchen";
import Bathroom from "../rooms/Bathroom";

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const TabTop = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();


function HomeScreen() {
  return (
      <TabTop.Navigator>
        <TabTop.Screen name="Livingroom" component={LivingRoom} />
        <TabTop.Screen name="Kitchen" component={Kitchen} />
        <TabTop.Screen name="Bathroom" component={Bathroom} />

      </TabTop.Navigator>
    
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

LivingRoom.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Kitchen from "./Kitchen";
import Bathroom from "./Bathroom";

const TabBottom = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default LivingRoom = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Image 
        source={require('../assets//images//livingroom.jpg')} 
        style={styles.image}
        
      />    
      <TabBottom.Navigator>
        <TabBottom.Screen name="LivingRoom" component={Bathroom} />
        <TabBottom.Screen name="Kitchen" component={Kitchen} />
      </TabBottom.Navigator>

    </View>
    
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height:450,
    width:400,
    marginRight:10,
    marginLeft:10,   

  }
})
```

routeNames.js

```
export default roomsList = {
  livingroom: {
    "tv":true,
    "laptop": true,
    "air-conditioner":true,
  },
  kitchen: {
    "fridge":true,
    "dining-table": true,
  },
  gameroom: {
    "computer":true,
    "headphones":true,
    "microphone":true,
    "cd-player":true,
  }
}
```

Comment: "Other question is how can I have bigger icon in bottom navigator? Now it seems so small" What do you mean here exactly? Do you mean the size of the text in the bottom bar and/or the size of the bar itself because I see no icons in the code or the image.

Comment: Yes sir, i mean the text size itself, i havent added icons yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change `roomsList` to something like this:

```
const roomsList = {
  livingroom: {
    TV: TV, // The value here is a component  
    LAPTOP: Laptop,
    AC: AirConditioner,
  },
  // Other rooms...
};
```

Here each key-value pair in `livingroom` identifies a bottom tab screen.

You can repeat the same idea for the other rooms in `roomsList`.

This way `LivingRoom` could look something like this:

```
const LivingRoom = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TabBottom.Navigator>
        {Object.keys(roomsList.livingroom).map(room => {
          return (
            <TabBottom.Screen
              name={room}
              component={roomsList.livingroom[room]}
            />
          );
        })}
      </TabBottom.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
};
```

For each key-value pair in the `livingroom` object we render a bottom tab in the `LivingRoom` component. Where the key corresponds to the name of the screen and the value corresponds with the component that the screen is going to render.

You could extend this idea by also looping over the keys in `roomsList` to dynamically render the top tab screens. I.e. For every room in `roomsList` we render a top tab and for every top tab we render one ore more bottom tabs.

---

For changing the font size of the tab labels you could set the `tabBarOptions` prop on the bottom tab navigator:

```
tabBarOptions={{
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    padding: 10,
  },
}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for nice explanation. I appreciate it Sir! I understand your codes, so clear